# Disable Control+Shift excluding all shortcuts related to those keys

Tags: windows, autohotkey

I want to disable the default windows `Control+Shift` (Windows keyboard layout switcher) shortcut but keep all the shortcuts that are related to `Control+Shift` such as `Control+Shift+D`. I have successfully disabled the `Control+Shift` with the given script:

```
; Disable the keyboard layout switcher
Ctrl & Shift::
return
```

Unfortunately this also disables all shortcuts related to those two keys.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to just disable the shortcut in the keyboard settings?

Comment: Yes, I suppose that is also an option, last resort one tho. Would prefer to have all my settings stored in one place.